# What are the names of these two succulent plants?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care

I want to know the name of these two plants and how to care for them?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second plant has many common names of which one is "Mother of Thousands", or [Bryophyllum daigremontianum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryophyllum_daigremontianum). It is a succulent native to Madagascar. Some things to note:

- all parts of the plant are poisonous
- it is not tolerant of frost
- it is extremely drought tolerant
- little "baby" plants form at the margins of the leaves and can drop off and form new plants
- tolerant a wide range of light, it does best in high light
- a free draining soil is preferred but, again, tolerant of wide soil range

Answer (score 4):

Plant 1 is indeed [Carpobrotus edulis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpobrotus_edulis) (ice plant). It grows on sand dunes near the ocean in temperate climates. It is considered an invasive species which grows rapidly covering large areas and reducing bio-diversity. Removing it once it is in place is also considered risky as it causes instability on the sandy soils during the rain season.

Comment: 'It is considered an invasive species' that depends on where you live. It is native to my country (South Africa) and we call them sour figs and make jam from the dried 'fruits' that form after the flower. Invasive species is a relative term ;)

Comment: I've also heard them referred to as Hottentot Figs amongst the English speaking people here in South Africa.  The Afrikaans people refer to it as "goena".  The sap from the leaves is used for treating cold-sores and mouth ulcers.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is called an ice plant

Comment: Please flesh out your answer. Explain how you came to your conclusion, and please give the latin name of [which ice plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_plant) you mean. Also, check out [our guide](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for answering properly.  Thanks!